# Inconsistent time complexity of membership test for Python range

Tags: python-3.x, range, membership

According to the documentation, membership testing for a Python range was constant-time ever since version 3.2. But when I tried measuring it (version 3.7.3), I observe linear-time when I search for the maximum or middle-ish integer but constant-time when I randomize the integer. How does that even make sense??[image: plot of the time complexity for range membership test]
The code:

```
import scipy as sp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import timeit
def in_range(maxlength = 1000, numlengths = 100, numSearch = 1000):
    lengths = sp.linspace(1, maxlength, num = numlengths, dtype = int)
    avgtimes = sp.zeros((3, lengths.size))

    for j, length in zip(range(numlengths), lengths):
        container = range(length)
        # test for last integer in range
        myInt = length-1
        avgtimes[0, j] = timeit.timeit('myInt in container',
                number = numSearch, globals = locals()) / numSearch

        # test for middle-ish integer
        myInt = length//2
        avgtimes[1, j] = timeit.timeit('myInt in container',
                number = numSearch, globals = locals()) / numSearch

        # test for random integer within range
        times = sp.zeros(numSearch)
        for i in range(numSearch):
            myInt = sp.random.randint(0, length)
            times[i] = timeit.timeit('myInt in container', number = 1,
                 globals = locals())
        avgtimes[2, j] = times.mean()

    for j in range(3):
        plt.plot(lengths, avgtimes[j])
    plt.legend(['maximum integer', 'middle-ish integer', 'random integer'])
    plt.xlabel('range size')
    plt.ylabel('average membership test time (seconds)')
```

Comment: Why do you have `number = 1` in the third case?

Comment: `number = numSearch` like the other sections would've searched the same random integer `numSearch` times, but I wanted to search for different random integers and average the runtimes. I could've tested `'sp.random.randint(0, length) in container'` to use `number=numSearch`, but I didn't want to include the random integer generation in the runtime.
Changing the other sections unnecessarily to the `number = 1` structure didn't seem to alter results.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with your usage of `timeit`, as I can reproduce your results with your code, BUT if I use IPython's `%timeit`, I observe constant timings.

Comment: I get constant-time when I do `%timeit x in range(x+1)` for a variety of `x`, too. But I have no idea how the timeit line is making the membership test for a range linear-time. If I change the container to a tuple, list, set, or dict, I observe the expected time complexities.